# Populating JComboBox using an MultiDimensional Array List

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I have been trying to populate a Eclipse GUI Java JComboBox using an Array list using constructors without any luck. This is what I have tried thus far.

```
import item.Item;  
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import java.util.ArrayList;  


public class SelectionScreen{
    private JFrame frame;
    static ArrayList< Item> list;
    private String items;

     public static void main (String[] args){  

        initialize();
     }
     public void initialize(){
        list = new ArrayList< Item >();  
        list.add(new Item("Strawberry,200,.25,.75);
        list.add(new Item("Banana,200,.25,1.00);  
        list.add(new Item("Oranges,200,.25,2.00);


       JcomboBox comboBox = newJcomboBox();
       ComboBox.setBounds(63,29,86,22)
       frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox); 

     // here is where I tried to fill the combobox

     //comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(Item.getName()))); //Wrong
     //comboBox.setModel(Item.getName); //Wrong

  //the following only loads the last item in the list which is Oranges
     for(Item i: list{

      comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(New String[] { 
      i.getName()})); 
      }

   // tried making a different list to collect my fruits.
     for(Item i: list){
     list2[ i.getName()];
     Item.length;
     } //which was a complete fail.
```

I am at complete lost here and not very experienced with Java. I can load the items just fine using 
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{ "Strawberry","Banana","Oranges"}));
but I won't know what fruits are in the list when I import them from a text file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*The following only loads the last item in the list which is Oranges.*/

for(Item i: list)
{
      comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { 
      i.getName()})); 
}
```

Don't keep creating a new ComboBoxModel inside the loop. You can't add more than one item to the model if you keep creating a new model. So you only see the last model created with the single item added to it. If you want to use this approach then you would create the model OUTSIDE of the loop and then just add items the model INSIDE the loop.

Actually you don't event need to create a combo box model. You can just add items directly to the combo box:

Something like:

```
for(Item i: list
{
      comboBox.addItem( i.getName() );
}
```

Another option is to add the Item object directly to the combo box. Then you can use a custom renderer to control which property of the Item object is display in the combo box. Check out [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for more information on this approach.

Comment: Worked Perfectly Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to show `Item` objects in a combobox then you should declare the `JComboBox` to store `Item` objects. That way you can easily add items without having to do any mucking around with models at all:

```
JComboBox<Item> itemsCombo = new JComboBox<>();
list.forEach(itemsCombo::add);
```

The value displayed in the combobox will be whatever is returned by `Item.toString`. If that's not what you want (because your `toString` returns a more complete description of the object - generally considered better practice) then it is fairly easy to write your own [Custom Renderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).

The only hackish downside of the `JComboBox` API is that you've got to cast the selected item:

```
Item selectedItem = (Item)itemsCombo.getSelectedItem();
```

This is ugly and I wish the API didn't require it but it's a small price to pay to avoid having to define your own model.

You can, in fact, avoid the cast by:

```
Item selectedItem = itemsCombo.getItemAt(itemsCombo.getSelectedIndex());
```

But that's just about as ugly.

As an aside, this is one of several areas in which the standard Java tutorial and samples are quite out of date so there's no blame here at all for not knowing to use generics.

Comment: `The value displayed in the combobox will be whatever is returned by Item.toString.` - you should not rely on the toString() implementation. Generally the toString() will display a String for all the properties of the object and the OP only want to display the name.

Comment: `it is fairly easy to write your own Custom Renderer.` - FYI you still need to be careful with a custom renderer since this will break some of the default functionality of the combo box. Check out the link provided in my answer for the problem (and potential solution).